# Differential Geometry of Surfaces in Higher Dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

I am looking for a reference that discusses "surfaces in higher dimensions." Specially I need a book or a paper about analogue of fundamental forms in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and other higher dimensions.

Thank you inadvance for your help.

Comment: Have you seen Kuhnel's book on diff geometry? He does evth in n dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Geometry of Submanifolds* by Bang-Yen Chen, (1973, M. Dekker, New York).

I know this is a late answer, but I recently have taken a look at this book. It discusses surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ so it might be an interesting reference.

Answer (score 1):

A classic and widely accepted general reference on this subject is:

***Foundations of Differential Geometry, vol. II***, by Kobayashi and Nomizu.

I would have a look at Chapter 7, especially section 5, p, 29.